# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image') in my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-props

I'm encountering an issue in my web application where I'm getting the following error in the browser console:

**Console**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
    at StarItem (StarItem.js:10:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

This error occurs in my JavaScript code, but I'm having trouble identifying the source of the problem and fixing it. Here's a simplified version of my code:

**StarItem.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Card.css";

function StarItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div className="card mb-3">
        <div className="card-header">
          <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={props.card.image} alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <h2>{props.card.name}</h2>
          <h5>{props.card.career}</h5>
          <div>Phone : {props.card.phone}</div>
          <div>Email : {props.card.email}</div>
          <div>Website : {props.card.website}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarItem;
```

**Stars.js**

```
import React from "react";
import StarItem from "./StarItem";

export function Stars() {
  const card = [
    {
      id: 1,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/200",
      name: "Walter White",
      career: "Actor",
      phone: "+490 123456",
      email: "wakter@gmail.com",
      website: "www.walterwhite.com",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/200",
      name: "Tom Cruise",
      career: "Actor",
      phone: "+490 123456",
      email: "tom-cruise@gmail.com",
      website: "www.tomcruise.com",
    },
  ];
  const actors = card.map((actor) => (
    <StarItem
      key={actor.id}
      image={actor.image}
      name={actor.name}
      career={actor.career}
      phone={actor.phone}
      email={actor.email}
      website={actor.website}
    />
  ));
  return <div className="row">{actors}</div>;
}

export default Stars;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Stars from "./components/Stars";
import Text from "./components/Text";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Text />
        <Stars />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want to display actor card with photo/name/career ... etc

Comment: There is no `card` prop. There is `image` prop though. Replace `props.card.image` with `props.image`